# How to get oldest date from collection list using but based on other clauses LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code:

```cs
MostRecentLogonList.Add(new LastLogons
{
    Id = id++,
    FirstName = FirstName,
    MiddleInitial = MiddleInitial,
    LastName = LastName,
    SAMAccountName = samaccountName,
    DistinguishedName = distinguishedName,
    OU = organizationalUnit,
    dnsHost = dnsHostName,
    lastLogon = lastLogon
});

InactiveList = InactiveList
   .Where(l => l.lastLogon <= CurrentDate.AddDays(-filterDays))
   .GroupBy(s => s.SAMAccountName)
   .Select(scope => scope.OrderBy(l => l.lastLogon).Last()).ToList();
```

"filterDays" is from an input field, set to 90.  What I am trying to do is display a list of users who have not logged in for the past 90+ days across 3 domain controllers. The above gives me the output of:

```
SAMAccountName    LastLogon      DomainController
test.user1        12/31/1600     dc02
test.user2        12/31/1600     dc02
test.user5        12/31/1600     dc01
test.user4        12/31/1600     dc03
```

Problem that I am having is, "test.user1" has a `LastLogon` of 9/30/2020 on "dc01" and "test.user4" has a `LastLogon` of 10/4/2020 on "dc01" as well, therefore, I do not want it to show up at all in the inactivity list.

I'm assuming I have to add something additional in the where clause but not sure exactly how to translate this:

"if a samaccount name has a `LastLogon` date less than or equal to the current date minus 90 days on dc01 but also has a `LastLogon` date greater than 90 days on since it logged into dc02, don't display it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Just need to make small change. You should apply `GroupBy` & `Select` `lastLogon` record and then use `Where` to filter. Try it like below.

```
InactiveList = InactiveList
   .GroupBy(s => s.SAMAccountName)
   .Select(scope => scope.OrderBy(l => l.lastLogon).Last())
   .Where(l => l.lastLogon <= CurrentDate.AddDays(-filterDays))
   .ToList();
```

**Edit**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7M396o here is a fiddle. Created small demo with required property only. You can see that with old code it will return 2 records while new code returns only one.

Comment: Thanks Karan, I will give that a try.  I did not know that you could actually orient it that way.  Thanks again, I'll let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, it ended up producing the same results :/

Comment: Please verify in fiddle added to the answer. It won't produce same result. You might be missing something.

Comment: Thank you for the Fiddle Karan.  I will export the data from my list and put it in the list in your Fiddle and see what happens.  My guess is, it may have something to do with the conversion from datatables with the dates that might be causing the LINQ filtering to not display properly.  I'll report back.  Thanks again, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Karan, please see my Fiddle done in MVC, I left some comments in there in the controller: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ihHFrF thanks again

Comment: And actually, it does appear to be working in the Fiddle, please confirm that you end up with test.user2 and test.user4 as well?  So something has to be going crazy with the dates in Datatables giving me incorrect results.

Comment: Yes, I verified in fiddle you added. It displays only two results for `test.user2` & `test.user4`.

Comment: I wanted to thank you again, you definitely answered it the first time and I am ashamed that I had the `InactiveList = InactiveList...` inside of a foreach loop not realizing it :/ after moving it out, it functioned as you have stated.  I have marked the answer.  You are a genius!!!